# Streaming data from MongoDB with Flink using Java API drivers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am attempting to read/write to MongoDB using Flink streaming capabilities. I already managed to write data to MongoDB using Flink's `RichSinkFunction` class. I was attempting to read using the opposite Flink's class, `RichSourceFunction`. However, it does not seem possible to stream documents from MongoDB one by one, whilst keeping track of the current "position" on the database.

I would like to know if any of you know of any method capable of doing this. I am aware of the publish/subscribe capabilities of MongoDB however I would prefer to avoid this methodology.